# What type of file can I use to group tifs and sign them without broke the signature so that I can regenerate that file after?

Tags: digital-signature

I use a ECM that a document is represented by many images (tifs). Each TIF representing a page of the document. The problem is that I need to digitally sign this document. I don't have nothing that represents only the document, so I want to avoid sign page by page.

So I need to group the tifs in a file, extract the byte array of this file, do the digital signature and discard that grouped file to some time later when I generate again to verify, it's good to have the same hash. Can somebody tell me in what way I can do that? What type of file Can I group this tifs?

Comment: TIFF files support multiple pages per file already. Why are you using a separate TIFF for each page separately?